# Can’t build app with the Facebook SDK 3.1 on iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated latest facebook sdk for ios 6 and configured it as done for previous ios version but it is giving me error that is listed below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
      +[FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSettings.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can u tell what this means and how can I resolve this...?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? i have the same issue right now...

Comment: I used deprecated files from latest facebook sdk.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i've just found a better solution straight from the facebook developer docs: "You should use the 'Optional' flag for iOS6-specific frameworks if you would like your app to also build for older versions of the operating systems"

Answer (score 3):

You should link Accounts.framework, Social.framework and AdSupport.framework binaries to your project. (Target settings -> Build Phases -> Link Binaries with Libraries)

Answer (score 2):

You have to link against the Accounts framework, among others. It’s described in [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/), RTFM.

Comment: I have added it as it is given in documentation  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Comment: In that case take a look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598209/facebook-ios-sdk-3-1-with-xcode-4-2-linker-errors), maybe that helps.

Comment: The tutorial you posted doesn’t say anything about linking against the required frameworks. Are you *positive* that you link the frameworks as described in the step 5 of the Getting Started guide?